# Forcing at least one true value of several SwitchPreferences

Tags: java, android

How do I enforce a true value from atleast one of two separate SwitchPreferences in Android? I am making an app where the user is able to decide if he or she wants to come in contact with males, females or both. As neither is not an option I basically want show_me_males to switch to true if it is set to false and show_me_females is set to false and vice versa.

```
<SwitchPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="show_me_males"
    android:summary="@string/pref_description_show_me_males"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_show_me_males" />

<SwitchPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="show_me_females"
    android:summary="@string/pref_description_show_me_females"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_show_me_females" />
```

Comment: Have you considered using e.g. ListPreference instead and having three options (m, f, both)?

Comment: Yes but I am trying to avoid "popup" settings.

Answer (score 0):

Use your [OnPreferenceChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setOnPreferenceChangeListener(android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener)) to display an error when both switches are set to `false`.

> As neither is not an option I basically want show_me_males to switch to true if it is set to false and show_me_females is set to false and vice versa.

I would avoid automatically changing switches for the user, it changes the expected behavior from every other app. If I accidentally click the switch I would rather have the option of "unclicking" that same switch than chasing down the unknown method of restoring a state.

Imagine if someone decided that shaking hands wasn't enough, they decided that they should violently pull on your hand at the same time... that's non-standard behavior and plain weird.

Comment: That is not really what I am after. I do not want any error message. I want the SwitchPreference to change its value if both are false.

Comment: If you really, really want to chose the user's target gender for them (again, I don't recommend it) then use the OnPreferenceChangeListener to check if both states are false, if so call [`setChecked()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/TwoStatePreference.html#setChecked(boolean)) on the other switch.